# mail function limitation PHP

Tags: php, email

I have a code running on localhost:

Firts at all, the code get some files that way:

```
$opts = array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$directory = "../V1/sector2/";
  $array_filename = glob($directory . "*.html");

 foreach($array_filename as $filename){ 
  $dan = file_get_contents($filename,  false, $context);
```

Then, the code uses PCRE functions in order to modify the html files and finally sending to an gmail email:

```
  $from = "test.com <noreply@prueba.com>";
  $to = "juanfernandoz@gmail.com";
 $subject = 
 echo "<div style='display:none;'>ob_get_contents();
   echo "</div>";
  $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n"
             ."MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n"
           ."To: $cliente <$email> \r\n"
           ."From: prueba <prueba@example.com> \r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$contenido,$headers);
```

The code works great but the probmen is that if I have, for example, 30 html files, Ive only get 11 files in my email and not the 30 files.

So, I think that maybe the mail function have a limit ifself.

What you think about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do your self a favour and stop using mail() and start using a library like [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or swiftmailer. I would never send anything but the most basic  text with mail() its terribly underpowered.

Comment: yes, but if I can use the mail function for what I need why modify the code and uses classes?

Comment: Are you adding these as attachments or as part of the body?

Comment: because you can do it in about 3 lines with much less chance of something going wrong - seems like a good reason to me

Answer (score 1):

Given that your recipient address is `juanfernandoz@gmail.com` I'm betting that you're hitting Gmail's preview-length limit. Gmail has a defined [limit for the body of 102K](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3610/maximum-file-size-for-html-email) when viewed in the standard gmail interface.

The email isn't actually missing anything, it just won't show more than that in the default view window. You should see a link at the bottom of the email to view the whole thing, which will pop out a new window with the longer text...This is the same reason then *embedded* (not referenced) images in gmail often come out displaying the image source: The image code gets cropped, resulting in the remaining fragment being translated literally.

Check for the **[Message clipped] View entire message** link at the bottom of the email (though this doesn't show for the mobile versions of Gmail). You can read more [here](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/when_it_comes_to_html_email_size_does_matter).

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of what it looks like in gmail? and/or echo out the HTML and provide a link to it?

Comment: well this is an example of an html file http://www.controljuridico.com/hey/rad5.htm  (for other reasons this link have htm instead html extension).

Comment: And you're including multiple files like this in one email?

Comment: And are they attachments or are then all in the body appended to one another? And what does PCRE have to do with it?